Как включить спутниковый слой в ymaps v3?
Как пользоваться  спутниковым слоем в ymaps v3, в объекте ymaps3 есть класс YMapDefaultSatelliteLayer, который 'работает' однако на нем отсутствуют какие либо метки, и я не вижу документации о том, как это сделать. Предпологал, что можно сделать так:


       const map = new YMap(document.getElementById('yandex-maps')!, { location: LOCATION });
   
   const satLayer = (window as any).ymaps3.YMapDefaultSatelliteLayer;

    map.addChild(new satLayer({visible: false, source: "satellite"}));
    map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({theme: 'light', visible: false, source: 'scheme'}));
    map.addChild(new YMapLayer({zIndex: 0, source: 'satellite', type: 'satellite'}))
    map.addChild(new YMapLayer({zIndex: 2, source: 'scheme', type: 'labels'}))
     map.addChild(new YMapLayer({zIndex: 4, source: 'scheme', type: 'icons'}))



Однако это не работает выдает ошибку следующего вида:
'Vector layer "scheme:labels" should have z-index less than raster layer "scheme:icons"'
Как включить спутник? :(

В API 3.0 нет публичного спутникового слоя. Также нет возможности включить режим гибридной карты со спутниковой подложкой и векторными объектами на ней.
Обратите внимание, использование любых недокументированных сущностей нарушает пользовательское соглашение сервиса. Такие решения, даже в случае их обнаружения, нет смысла использовать для проектов, требующих хотя бы минимальную стабильность, поскольку любые внутренние методы могут быть изменены в любой момент.
